# Como criar filtros para categorias com php e html para usar em pagina WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filtro

Olá,

Gostaria de criar um filtro para categorias dos posts no WP. 
Como nesse exemplo https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/N6vrp.

Mas não manjo muito de php, então não sei como faço, para que quando eu clique no botão da 'categoria1' só apareça posts dessa categoria. E quando clicar em 'Todos' aparecer os posts de todas as categorias..

Meu código está assim, por enquanto.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
/* 
Template Name: Arquivo Posts
*/
?>
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: white; margin-bottom: 30px;">Noticias</h1>
    <div class="filtro" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="<?php get_posts('orderby=date&order=DESC&category_name=categoria1'); ?>">Categoria 1</a> 
        <a>Categoria 2</a> <a>Todos</a> </div>

<div class="row">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 " style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="imgPost"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p><em><?php echo ucfirst(get_the_time('l, j \d\e F \d\e Y')); ?></em></p>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p><?php _e('Desculpe, não há posts a serem exibidos.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Alguém sabe me ajudar?

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Caroline, tudo bem?

Necessitei realizar um tipo de filtro como esse uma vez, e consegui fazer com alguns passos.

Vamos lá:

1 - Primeiro você deverá baixar o plugin Isotope e depois inserir dentro de alguma pasta do seu tema do Wordpress (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/);

2 - Depois inserir esse código abaixo na functions.php do seu tema do Wordpress:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery_to_my_theme' );

function add_jquery_to_my_theme() {
// scrap WP jquery and register from google cdn - load in footer
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js", false, null, true );    
// load jquery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

if (!is_admin()) add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_isotope' );

function load_isotope() {
// script will load in footer
wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope-js',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/jquery.isotope.min.js', true );
}
```

O primeiro *if* você adiciona o jQuery em seu tema, e o segundo *if* você chama o plugin Isotope. Lembre-se de definir corretamente o caminho exato do plugin em seu tema.

3 - Depois em seu template de página no tema, deverá adicionar esse código abaixo:

```
<ul id="filtros">
    <?php
        $terms = get_terms("category");
        $count = count($terms);
            echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-filter=".all" class="active">Todos</a></li>';
        if ( $count > 0 ){

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-filter=".'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<div id="post">

   <?php 
   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

      $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );                      
      if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

          $links = array();

          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
              $links[] = $term->name;
          }

          $tax_links = join( " ", str_replace(' ', '-', $links));          
          $tax = strtolower($tax_links);
      else :    
      $tax = '';                    
      endif; 
      ?>

      <div class="all post-item <?php echo $tax; ?>">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <div class="imgPost"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
              <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <p><em><?php echo ucfirst(get_the_time('l, j \d\e F \d\e Y')); ?></em></p>
          </a>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

4 - Agora você vai inserir, dentro do header ou no footer do seu tema (faça testes), a função que faz com que o recurso de filtro funcione:

```
<script>
    (function($){

    var $container = $('#post');

    // create a clone that will be used for measuring container width
    $containerProxy = $container.clone().empty().css({ visibility: 'hidden' });   

    $container.after( $containerProxy );  

    // get the first item to use for measuring columnWidth
    var $item = $container.find('.post-item').eq(0);

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $(window).smartresize( function() {

            // calculate columnWidth
            var colWidth = Math.floor( $containerProxy.width() / 2 ); // Change this number to your desired amount of columns

            // set width of container based on columnWidth
            $container.css({
                width: colWidth * 2 // Change this number to your desired amount of columns
            })
            .isotope({

                // disable automatic resizing when window is resized
                resizable: false,

                // set columnWidth option for masonry
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: colWidth
                }
            });

        // trigger smartresize for first time
        }).smartresize();
    });

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filtros a').click(function(){

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector, animationEngine : "css" });
        $('#filtros a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;

    });

} ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

5 - Por fim, adicione o css:

```
/**** Isotope Filtering ****/

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height;
     -moz-transition-property: height;
      -ms-transition-property: height;
       -o-transition-property: height;
          transition-property: height;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
       -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}

/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0s;
          transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

A partir daí já é pra funcionar. Depois ficaria a seu critério depois ir melhorando o visual para se adequar com as suas necessidades.

Se ainda sim não funcionar, verifique o caminho do seu plugin se está exato ou faça mais testes retirando o código do primeiro if, no passo 2, pois pode ser conflito de jQuery.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vou tentar agora e te falo os resultados, muito obrigada

Comment: Oi, eu coloquei assim no meu functions 
function load_isotope() {
// script will load in footer
wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope-js',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', true );
}

Mas não está funcionando, pq o filtro não funciona. Queria saber se tem como  nessa função, apontar direto para o link. que seria esse, https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js, correto?

Comment: E no 2 passo, onde eu chamo o "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" eu já tenho um script no meu header que carrega exatamente o mesmo link, sendo assim a primeira função é necessária? 
Me desculpe se as perguntas parecem bobas, mas não manjo muito de Js nem de Php, eu sei bem html e css. Essas outras ainda estou bem no começo. Obrigada.

Comment: Caroline, você chegou a olhar no código fonte de sua página pelo browser, para verificar se o isotope foi carregado corretamente? Tipo, quando você clica na url por lá, abre o arquivo js?

Comment: Se ele estiver abrindo normalmente pelo código fonte, pode ser apenas conflito de jQuery, pois é como te falei, pode ocorrer isso pelo fato de já existir uma chamada do jQuery em sua header. Tenta retirar o primeiro if do código que te passei.

Comment: Brício, verifiquei e está la sim, até tirei uma captura de tela pra te mandar, mas eu não sei enviar aqui dos comentarios. E abre o arquivo normalmente. Tirei o primeiro if mas tb não está funcionando. 
Os links do filtro estão assim. 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-filter=".sistema">Sistema</a>
Talvez o script do passo 4 que ñ esteja funcionando? estou colocando ele acima do </header>. E está aparecendo no browser tb,normal. coloquei esse script em todas as posições no footer, mas tb sem sucesso.

Comment: Você teria como mostrar em algum ambiente de demonstração ou só está local no momento?

Comment: Desculpe! No passo 3, note que esqueci de fechar a <div id="post">

Comment: Caroline, faça o seguinte: Conserta o fechamento da <div id="post">; depois retira os dois ifs da sua functions.php e chama apenas o Isotope em seu rodapé, da maneira padrão: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

Comment: Eu fiz aqui rapidamente e já funcionou para mim. Lembre-se de inserir a função do passo 4 logo abaixo a chamada do plugin.

Comment: Ah! Outro detalhe que percebi é que você terá que baixar uma versão mais antiga do plugin Isotope ( v1.5.25 - https://redvinestudio.com/demo-pages/wordpress-isotope-portfolio/js/jquery.isotope.min.js ). Testei com a versão atual e não funcionou, ok?

Comment: Consegui!! Mas tem um espaço enorme entre um post e outro, e não consigo resolver. Já olhei nas classes que estão no css que me passou, mas nada está relacionado. Parece que tem uma margem gigante na esqueda e direita de cada post. E colocando dentro de grades e colunas como col-sm-4, só diminui a foto. o espaço continua. sabe me dizer se tem alguma classe que esta fazendo isso?

Comment: Certo! Que bom que deu certo! No caso aí vc não vai precisar usar essas classes do bootstrap. A quantidade de coluna você define na própria função, nessa parte: // calculate columnWidth

Comment: Brício, muito obrigada. deu tudo certinho :3

Comment: Ótimo! Se você puder marcar como resolvido, vai facilitar para outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score -2):

Usando somente o PHP é difícil fazer essa funcionalidade acontecer. Basicamente quando fazemos um looping passamos o parâmetro da categoria que queremos filtrar...

Primeiro é importante entender que você precisa estar em uma página do template "category.php" e lá ter uma looping das suas categorias. Esse looping é basicamente um array que poderá conter todas suas categorias cadastradas no Wordpress.

Nessa situação quando você selecionar um item dessa lista o Wordpress recarregará a página passando o parâmetro escolhido para a URL e exibindo os posts desta página.

Porém para fazer a troca dos posts sem que a página recarregue é necessário usar Ajax.

Eu já usei algo próximo a este exemplo:
https://kilowp.com/tutorials/create-an-ajax-powered-posts-filter/

Existem alguns plugins que facilitam bastante a inclusão dessa funcionalidade ao tema.

Eu já usei esse plugin e funcionou muito bem:
https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-filter-search/

Comment: Eu vou tentar e te falo os resultados, obrigada

Comment: Obrigada também. Mas a resposta dele, teve um resultado mais imediato :3